# gradle android proguard error

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I am having this issue and seem can't figure it out when building gradle android with proguard:
Can't read [C:\Users\xxx\dev\xyz\Xyz-nextgen\build\exploded-bundles\XyzCommonXyz_volleyUnspecified.aar\libs\android-support-v13.jar(;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Duplicate zip entry [android/support/a/a/b.class == android-support-v13.jar:android/support/v13/app/FragmentCompat$FragmentCompatImpl.class])
There are 3 library projects and one app project. 
All projects use only one android-support-v13.jar.
Thanks.
Andy

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will probably get a better response to questions if you try to format them to make them more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Open the module's gradle.build file and

In

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.3.1.jar')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Change

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
```

To

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
```

make sure u have updated build tools in the sdk manager and let us know if that works